# cannot fine .csproj files, trying to install selenium.webdriver through NuGet package vscode

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code

I am working in the Visual Studio code environment. I am attempting to install selenium in vscode. I have selenium installed on my system but when running an import selenium command I receive a selenium module does not exist. So I installed the NuGet extension and upon trying to install selenium.webdriver I am directed to a list of versions, form which I select 4.0.0- alpha05 but then receive the following error.

```
Cannot find any .csproj or .fsproj file for your project! Please fix this error and try again.
```

I made sure to verify that all my system was up to date and that all elements of the python environment of my system are running smoothly. I tried to import selenium through anaconda environment as a last resort but still I am receiving this message. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to just install selenium and already have pip configured to your path, you need to type:

pip3 install selenium

Now that it is installed you want to install a driver and make sure to install the same driver version as your web browser. You also need to add this driver to the path so you can access it from anywhere on your laptop via code.

Comment: I have already installed selenium. However for the sake of clarity can you elaborate on what you. mean by configured to my path? Further what exactly do you mean to install driver, how would I go about this?

Comment: What I mean by path is, you can use pip in any folder on your laptop, also you need to make sure you pip installed for python 3 and not python 2 if you have them both installed. If you did that you should be able to import selenium

Comment: Also go to this link for the chromedriver, it is what you use to open an instance of google chrome with selenium: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Comment: I am running pip 20.2.2 from the command line. how would it be configured to my path, are you referring to PATH or .bash_profile ? I am working on a Mac OS system

Comment: the pip is for python 3 and everything is up to date on the system.

Comment: I am refering to PATH and if the pip is up to date their should not be an error, the only error that comes to mind is pip in this kind of scenario or incorrect spelling

Comment: how did you go about adding it to your PATH? I do not believe that I have pip in my PATH

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-the-path-variable-in-mac

Comment: thanks, I actually tried to follow this tutorial earlier, but it seemed that for the life of me, I could not get it to work. How did you find the python install directory, perhaps I did it incorrect?

Comment: Try this video instead on how to install pip then, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3yH6FfD_Wk